# Two log files on Joomla install

Tags: joomla, logs, errorhandling, configandlog

Is anyone seeing multiple logs on Joomla installs in the `ConfigAndLog` directory?

Reason we care is items from only one of them get actually rendered in the Log Viewer (in CiviCRM admin UI: Admin >> Administration Console >> View Log).

This is with CiviCRM 5.50.3, but we've seen this behavior for a while now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a multilingual site? If yes then this change will be in 5.52 to just have one file: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23722

Comment: Thank you for the info. Ours is a non-multilingual; also single-site (if that matters)